# How to draw a transparent rectangle?

Tags: java-me

How to draw a transparent rectangle in j2me?

Comment: Do you mean with some kind of alpha blending, or do you mean a rectangle with color fill?

Comment: yes some thing like that.......

Answer (score 1):

Transparency is supported only in immutable images, i.e. images loaded from files. So you can create appropriate image. Or create transparency via filling its transparency parts with background color.

Comment: What code do you need? Image img = Image.createImage("/someImgWithTransparency.png"); gr.drawImage(img, 0, 0, Graphics.TOP | Graphics.LEFT)

Answer (score 1):

Nokia has some functions that will allow you to draw transparent rects and polygons
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Java/_zip/GUID-237420DE-CCBE-4A74-A129-572E0708D428/com/nokia/mid/ui/DirectGraphics.html

However if you want it to be a generic solution you should create a transparent image in code and draw it in the appropriate position. Create a int array with size = width*height then fill it with the required color (for example 0x550000ff for semi transparent blue) and create the image using Image.createRGBImage (and setting the last parameter to true).

```
int[] tmpArray = new int[width*height];
for(int i=tmpArray.length;i--!=0;)
    tmpArray[i] = 0x550000ff;
Image transparentRectImg = Image.createRGBImage(tmpArray,width,height,true);
```

Also don't forget that some old j2me devices do not support alpha transparency even in images.